# Biblioteca #include <HsFFi.h>

Tags: c, cmd, biblioteca, haskell

Ola, estou integrando um sistema baseado em C com Haskell, porem preciso da biblioteca #include , o conteúdo que achei na internet não tem me ajudado em quase nada, se alguém souber algo desde já agradeço

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: <HsFFI.h> não existe no diretório padrão de includes, usualmente /usr/include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem vindo ao **SO/pt**

Verifique a pasta **`C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.5\lib\include`**, nela vais encontrar o arquivo **`HsFFi.h`** e as possíveis dependências.

**Obs.: 1)** Use uma pasta para o seu projeto, não é recomendável usar a área de trabalho.

**Obs.: 2)** Obviamente, estou considerando que já tenhas [baixado e instalado](http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html) o [haskell](https://www.haskell.org/).

Comment: Obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Show de bola tchê!